# Is there a way to control microphone through JS?

Tags: javascript, html, mqtt, microphone

I'm new to JS and hoping someone can assist me...

I made a website that switches between pages by listening for MQTT messages. I want to be able to control my microphone through mqtt as well.

for example in my JS code,

if received MQTT message (micro_off) then.. mute microphone

else keep it unmuted.

Comment: You can control the current browser page's access to the microphone ... but mute/unmute for, say, a different program is not possible

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe there is a way to control the microphone through the command line? maybe some python script?

Comment: probably - there may be a way to do it in javascript using nodejs - I didn't consider that since you tagged "html"